# Why MySQL disable load local infile is not working?

Tags: mysql, linux, security

As part of security hardening, I am trying to disable local_infile and Prevent someone accessing local files of Operating System. As per the documentation I can disable it by either setting the variable `local-infile=0` in my.cnf or start mysqld service with option `--local-infile=0`. But with any of the option I am able to load the local files.

I tried first adding in `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
```

After that I confirmed the changes got reflected.

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | OFF   | 
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then from mysql client I loaded the local file using load_file

```
mysql> SELECT  load_file("/etc/passwd");
```

The above command  shows the content of /etc/passwd file, even though local_infile is disabled.Can someone tell what is going wrong here?

I repeated the same steps from passing `mysqld --local-infile=0` but no change. I have also tried starting `mysql` client with `--local-infile=0` option but no difference.

Comment: I've done exactly what you have and it is working for me. The contents of any file come back as NULL, if I attempt to use load_file

Answer (score 0):

Use this query in your mysql database

STEP:1

```
  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

STEP:2

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
```

STEP:3

```
 SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

Comment: My intention is to disable local_infile and prevent some one accessing the os local file.

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question!